# How to select different hue for Seaborn RegPlot

Tags: python, seaborn

I am using a seaborn regplot with the following code :

```
sns.relplot(x="NumCustomers", y="TotalSales", hue = 'StoreLabel', data=stores_month, height = 5, aspect = 2, s = 100);
```

To generate the following plot :

[image]

But the colors are hard to differentiate, after scouring google managed to get this code :

```
sns.color_palette("tab10")
```

but nothing happens. How can I change the color pallet to something with better contrast? preferably the tab10 palette.

Comment: Did you try `sns.relplot(...,  palette='tab10')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  try
  sns.set_palette("Blues")
  or
  sns.set_palette("Dark")

 sns.set_style()
 1.white
 2.dark
 3.whitegrid
 4.darkgrid
 5.ticks
 The set palette api must occur before the relPlot
 other apis to try catDist, distPlot, catPlot

 I think catPlot would work better
```